# How to split image based on font characteristics

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr

I want to find an algorithm that split images based on font differences.

Example 1:

[image: Example 1]

Example 2:

[image: Example 2]

In Example 1, the image would be split into "Key" and "SOME TEXT HERE". Example 2 follows a similar pattern.

Are two, separate algorithms needed? Is there a computer vision program accurate enough to determine that "Key" in Example 2 is bolded?

Finally, I'm familiar with mechanisms to split on whitespace, but I'm encountering instances where such a method fails.

Comment: What about doing image difference and thresholding and morphology to clean it up and then get the contours.

Comment: what happen if you add dilation operation to you threshold mask it join the neighborhood pixels to build two blocks and then extract them